# Excel Worksheet_Change not detecting changes

Tags: excel, vba

Unfortunately Worksheet_change is not working for me. I am using a Sheet where the first column is NOW() function. If I click anywhere in the excel the time on this cell changes, but the Worksheet_Change just don't detect it.

A2 is using =NOW()

Anyone knows how to fix this issue? I have tried several different ways and no one works.

```
'Option Explicit
'Option Base 1
Dim xVal As Double
'Update by Extendoffice 2018/8/22
'Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate(ByVal Target As Range)
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Target.Address = Range("$A$2").Address Then
        'Rows(3).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        'Range("$A$3").Value = Now
        'Range("$B$3").Value = xVal
        'Range("$C$3").Value = Range("$C$2").Value
    'Else
        If xVal <> Range("$B$2").Value Then
            Debug.Print xVal & " <- xVal IF"
            Debug.Print Range("B2").Text & "<- Text IF"
            Rows(3).Insert Shift:=xlDown
            Range("$A$3").Value = Now
            Range("$B$3").Value = xVal
            Range("$C$3").Value = Range("$C$2").Value
        End If
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    xVal = Range("$B$2").Value
End Sub
```

Comment: `worksheet_change` events are not sensitive to formulas. You must make a physical sheet change to trigger this macro. You may want to look into other events that you could make use of.

Comment: Whenever, you click, now() will be different. So, why you want to check if it is changed? You can do away with the condition? and you wont have this question :)

Comment: What event can replace worksheet change? Basically I have a formulate calculating a DDE Link and when this formula value changes I need to record it on a new line to keep a history. I am using NOW just to try to capture changes on some cell for record the important values.

Comment: `Worksheet_Calculate`.

Comment: What are you monitoring and what are you changing afterwards? e.g. monitoring Cell A2 or the bottom most cell with data in column A or all cells in column A? I there was a change then change values in the below row?? Be a little more specific (especially for the monitoring part), please.

Comment: I already tried Worksheet_Calculate. My B2 cell is a value calculated from Sheet1 A12 and this A12 is a DDE Link. Everytime this value change I need to record it on Sheet2, keeping the history. That´s why I am inserting a new line below the A2 to store the record. Basically we have: 

`
A2                                    B2           =INT(A2) <--- Just to get the data only.
02/04/2020 22:17:01 50,69 02/04/2020
`

Answer (score 1):

### A Worksheet_Calculate Event Study

[Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1E8FbgIAEpbKHalTZb_ywwfFNk8o3n6qZ)

Cell `A2` in worksheet `Sheet1` contains the formula `=B2`.

**Sheet1**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    WsCalc
End Sub

' Only to trigger the calculate event when different cell is selected.
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2") = Int(Rnd() * 2 + 1)
End Sub
```

**ThisWorkbook**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    WsCalc
End Sub
```

**Module1**

```
Option Explicit

Public lngSource As Long ' Current Source Value

Sub WsCalc()

    Dim rngSource As Range        ' Source Cell Range

    ' Create a reference to Source Cell Range (rngSource).
    Set rngSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2")

    ' When the workbook opens, Current Source Valuec (lngSource) is equal to "".
    ' Therefore:
    If lngSource = 0 Then
        ' Initialize Current Source Value (lngSource) i.e. write value
        ' of Source Cell Range (rngSource) to Current Source Value (lngSource).
        lngSource = rngSource.Value
        MsgBox "Monitoring started (lngSource=" & lngSource & ")."
        Exit Sub
    End If

     ' If you need disabling events, this is how you implement it. Not needed
     ' in this code.
'    Application.EnableEvents = False
        On Error GoTo ProgramError
        ' Check value of Source Cell Range (rngSource)
        ' against Current Source Value (lngSource).
        If rngSource.Value <> lngSource Then
            ' The value has changed.
            MsgBox "The value has changed from '" & lngSource & "' to '" _
              & rngSource.Value & "'."
            lngSource = rngSource.Value
        Else
            ' The value hasn't changed (usually no code).
            MsgBox "Value NOT changed, still '" & lngSource & "'"
        End If

SafeExit:
'    MsgBox "Enabling events before exiting."
'    Application.EnableEvents = True
Exit Sub

ProgramError:
    ' Improve this error handling.
    MsgBox "An unexpected error occurred."
    On Error GoTo 0
    GoTo SafeExit

End Sub
```

Comment: VBasic2008, your code is working. The problem is that Excel is crashing because of the updates. The DDE link is updating data so fast that make excel closes unexpected.

Comment: @JMB: You mean in your workbook when you applied this system? You can edit your question and put in the new code, or you can supply a link to the file on google drive, dropbox ... for me to have a look.